# How Alfresco stores metadata in DB using java client

Tags: alfresco

I am new to Alfresco,When we use separate java API to connect to Alfresco repository to upload the document without using alfresco UI, how does it stores the metadata of the document in alfresco DB, whether it stores automatically or we will have to store it from our side by writing Java code?
Please suggest.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about API, maybe for others will be good to provide details how you are connecting and storing the document. 
As far I can remember, in case if Alfresco was connected using sharepoint / webdav, then documents got automatically indexed metadata in the db

Comment: Just use CMIS or the Alfresco Public API, then Alfresco will take care all of that for you

Answer (score 0):

Alfresco stores files on the file system (aka "content store") and metadata in a relational database. This separation is something you, as a developer, do not have to worry about, ever. Alfresco objects are abstractions that join the content and the content's metadata into a single object.

This is true regardless of whether you are using a web client, an Alfresco API, CMIS, or anything else you can think of to manage objects in the repo.